# C# Oracle data provider (Oracle DataAccess.Dll) Connection request timed out

Tags: c#, oracle9i

**select statement for specific table in oracle db works fine**.

But when I update a record using its primary key throws error as **Connection request timed out**

-anand

Comment: I don't have experience to work with oracle. But firstly you should check that connected user have permission for update data also you can increase Time Out option in connection string (by default this value equals 15 seconds)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is that you have a lock on the table.

Do you have toad or some other connection to the db open? If so, commit / rollback all other connections and then try again. You can also use Toad or a other program to see if you have any locks on that table.